# Inline content with BootStrap Only,

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

I try to inline the button to the right with bootstrap only.

```js
const todoList = ({ todos }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ListGroup>
        {todos.map((todo) => {
          return (
            <div key={todo.todo_id} className="">
              <ListGroupItem
                className="mt-1 mx-5 text-center rounded-pill inline"
                color="success"
              >
                <h5 className=""> {todo.content}</h5>
                <button type="button" className="  btn btn-dark rounded-pill ">
                  Dark
                </button>
              </ListGroupItem>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </ListGroup>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I tried to use the form and flex options without any success. it renders it to me in a small bubble strange way.

Comment: Check which bootstrap version is used in your application.

Comment: If we think the child code is correct then we can inspect the parent code. Sometimes we get the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Removed the attribute `color="success"` from `<ListGroupItem>` and add `bg-succes` or `text-success` bootstrap class accordingly to the same.

```
<div key={todo.todo_id} className="">
   <ListGroupItem className="mt-1 mx-5 text-center rounded-pill inline text-success">
      <h5 className=""> {todo.content}</h5>
      <button type="button" className="btn btn-dark rounded-pill">
         Dark
      </button>
   </ListGroupItem>
</div>
```

If you want to add `<h5>` and `<button>` to all the list items then it would be better to put `<h5>` and `<button>` elements inside the `<ListGroupItem>` component. Then code will look like following:

```
<div key={todo.todo_id} className="">
  <ListGroupItem className="mt-1 mx-5 text-center rounded-pill inline text-success" />
</div>
```

Here h5 and button element is inside ListGroupItem.js component.

For inlining the list item in the list to make it a horizontal list, you need to use `list-inline` class to `<ul>` or `<ol>` and `list-inline-item` class to `<li>`. Your snippet will look like:

```
<div key={todo.todo_id} className="">
  <ListGroupItem className="mt-1 mx-5 text-center rounded-pill list-inline text-success" />
</div>
```

Comment: I understood your point but the inline is do not work and the button and the text are still on different lines

Comment: To display all the item in the list in Horizontal, use `list-inline` class in `<ul>` or `<ol>` instead of `inline` class and use `list-inline-item` class in `<li>` .